# How to use the substr function in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, match, substr

This is my solution to export data from mongo into a table into oracle, if there's a better way, I'd appreciate that as well.

My current query is:

```
db.getCollection('table_name').find({"key.specificKey": "value"})
```

What I want to do is select a specific substring to display. I tried using the substr function as found in the [mongodb docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/substr/). However this wasn't working for me.

```
db.getCollection('table_name').aggregate({columnName: {$substr: ["$key", 0, 2]}})
```

I also tried using the match function as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25436630/mongodb-how-to-find-and-then-aggregate). But that was also not working.

```
db.getCollection('table_name').aggregate($match: {"key.specificKey": "value"}, {columnName: {$substr: ["$key", 0, 2]}})
```

Can someone correct my syntax to do this? I'm using robomongo, if that matters.

Sample data:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("hey"),
    "key" : {
        "keyId" : NumberLong(1234),
        "keyName" : "valueName",
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add a sample document from your collection ?

Comment: Just added a sample one. Although, I'm not sure how helpful it will be, it has sensitive data I had to scrub

Comment: You are missing [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) stage in aggregate. Try

    `db.getCollection('table_name').aggregate([
      {$match: {"key.specificKey": "value"}}, 
      {$project:{columnName: {$substr: ["$key.keyName", 0, 2]}}}
    ])`

Comment: Yes, you're completely right!

Comment: @Veeram how do I select multiple substrings? I'm trying to figure out how to use $and. And where to put it. Also, is there a way to concat my own string onto my selects?

Comment: 1.Add field with requested substring into project comma separated. 2.You can see the usage of  [`$and`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/and/). 3.You can use [`$concat`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/concat/) to add your string. Please consider creating a question with the expected json output and some sample input documents if you need detailed answer.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48692010/how-to-do-string-concatenation-in-mongodb

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to use the [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) stage in the aggregation pipeline for this to work, as follows:

```
db.getCollection('table_name').aggregate([{
    $match: {
        "key.specificKey": "value"
    }
}, {
    $project: {
        columnName: {
            $substr: ["$key", 0, 2]
        }
    }
}])
```

Comment: Sweet, thank you this worked! I can't believe I didn't notice that...  I can't upvote you, but I selected it as the correct answer

Comment: `$gt` has a different structure when using with the aggregration pipeline, like a lot of other operators. SEE: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/gt/

Comment: Lol yup, figured it out, thanks!! Can I do string concat with my selected string? Do you know about this? If you don't it's okay, I can create a new question

Comment: @user9333933 I would use a [$let](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/let/) to create a variable of the new (substringed) value then [$concat](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/concat/) that. Also `substr` is deprecated since version 3.4 [$substrBytes](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/substrBytes/#mongodb-expression-exp.-substrBytes) is recommended since.